# Why do we need Data Warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse

I was wondering about why and when we need a data warehouse, I mean the main goal of data warehouse is to provide a reporting from multidimentional view, but in some case there is a way to build a report using DBMS, it can produce a report from multidimentional view, about the size of the database, the size can be made incrementally, and about integration DBMS also can make integration from many data source and if they have a different key from many data source, dbms can fix it (althought we're not using data warehouse), from the peformance side, how much time it will take to generate a report from operational data store and generate a report from a data warehouse, are the processing time is having a big gap?

Sorry for bad english and weird question, I'm still learning about data warehouse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### **Why do we need data warehouse?**

I will share experience of me and company I work for, how and when we have decided to build data warehouse.

1. **Historical Data**

   Our ERP back-end is designed to cover one year of data (because of high volume data). All predefined reports are built to watch one year data. So, if you want to examine sales growth per customer or product you have to run report twice (from two sources - you pick source on login page) and than lookup values in excel.
2. **Multiple source**

   At some point we bought third party ordering solution (tablet order -> web service -> database) for business enhancement. ERP provider took a fortune from us  'to integrate it in system'.
3. **Bad data**

   Our CFO and his team needed a whole week to generate good P'n'L report. Why? Analytic data was wrong, so they have to go row per row (in excel export) and to search for abnormalities.
4. **Reports performance**

   Sometimes it took over two hours to generate yearly report of sales grouped by product, customer and day.
5. **Adding intern grouping**

   When management decide to separate customers or products by another criteria, we have to pay ERP providers, and also we have wait for 1-3 weeks. And guess what, Sales Manager gives quit, and new one is asking new grouping types. It costs (time & money).

What to do? To change ERP system, or to create data warehouse? We spend months and months to create custom system from theirs standard product. We spent money and money to pay theirs extra hours. We have more than 250 employers to teach how to use new system. We have to wait for at least one year for new ERP provider to develop our custom needs.

Then we bought company which is the competition. We wanted to track our progress in comparison to their sales value. **We decided to build data warehouse!**

And we made our lives easier. After that, we bought **Warehouse management system**, **Geo-Tracking Logistic Management System**, another company, and guess what? We have data we want, in way we want, with great scalability for no giving money to ERP provider.

Now, our data warehouse is providing:

1. Historical Data from our company, and two others company with perfect keys mapping.
2. Multiple Source, our current data, our historical data, bought companies historical data, WMS, TMS, Ordering System and Excel Sheets (KPIs, targets, estimation, ect)
3. We made a rules table, so CFO and his team have only to administer on rules table, we always get good data, and wrong data is automatically reported (on daily bases) to specific department in order to change it.
4. Oh, managers just love OLAP. It's blazing fast.
5. Using Excel tables as one of source, we can easily map products or customers if management wants new grouping.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience sir @fenix thats great because i can know more from how actually datawarehouse use on a company :) , but if in case the datawarehouse is already designed for 5 year - 10 years of data, in your case why the report produced have an abnormality is it wrong on design? or because the dbms itself cannot     support a "always changing" report ? if i have a transactional database, can i use that into BI tools like clickview excel or etc as data source to produce multidimentional report? thanks sir for sharing, there's no best way than learning from who have done it!

Comment: Let me explain on example: For each invoice, employee can 'attach\

Comment: Let me explain on example: For each invoice, employee can 'attach' analytics (HR, Logistic, IT, Sales Marketing ect). Due to lot of work, employee 'attach' HR analytics to invoice headed to petrol company by mistake. It's actually Logistic. Management can be thought that salaries are too high :-)
With rules which cannot exist in ERP, reports are pointing to POSSIBLE abnormalities.

Answer (score 0):

1. Aggregation: By month, By product, etc. Obviously, we can do it right away in Transactional DB (Using SQL query, calculation, etc.), but why we avoid that?

   - We don't want to impact the Transactional DB!
   - We want to separate non-transactional users with transactional users.
   - We want to display reports. To display a report, we need to do a complex calculation, so we don't want to harm the Transactional DB during the processing of reporting.
2. Historical data: Transactional DB is only for current/transaction data, old data will/may be archived. But we can query and combine both archived data and transactional data?

   - But where is the archived data? How do we get that data? How can we combine in run-time? That's a headache!
3. Combining of several data sources: We have multiple sources of our business, the reporting must display the combined information from all sources. So we need a place to hold these data, that's why we need a data warehouse.
4. From transactional DB, we have data, we are going to use that data for reporting. But what if that data do not well format, what if that data is NULL (but the business rule is NOT NULL), what if that data is incorrect, and more and more. That's why we need to Transform data to the correct format, correct business rule, etc. But after that, where do we want to store it? That's when data warehouse come into place.